# Publish image attachment in azure (Playwright in TS)

Tags: azure, yaml, automated-tests, playwright

I have automated E2E tests written in TypeScript using Playwright.

These tests run automatically every day in Azure DevOps. I need to publish images in attachments in tests results in Azure.

I have `screenshot: 'on'` in my playwright config file and try to call `testInfo.attach(...)`.

The png files really exists. If I publish them via yml file

```
- publish: ./tests-out
 displayName: Tests output as artifact.
 artifact: tests-out
 condition: always()
```

Zip file exists and contains required png files. But I need them in result detail in azure. Is that even possible If I use TypeScript? I know NUnit in C# allows that.